# Best possible regression models

Tags: regression

I am looking for different types of regression models for such data in which the dependent variable is always decreasing with the independent variables.

The two's, I know and have used so for are

```
Y = C + C_a A + C_b B
```

and

```
Y = C + C_a A + C_b B + C_a2 A^2 + C_b2 B^2 + C_ab A B
```

The second one give me the best fit so far. I want to try some other ones too but don't know. Please suggest some.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying lots and lots of terms without a basis for any one is liable to give you non-reproducible results.  Try dividing your data set in two and, on the first set, visually examining scatterplots of each predictor with Y.  You might also call up a lowess curve to assess the nature of any relationship.  Then if you see a complex relationship such as would be defined by, say, a cubic or quartic term, you can test such a term on your holdout set.